# How to get multiple random values from a specified area in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am trying to create a workout simulator. If the user wants to target two areas, I want to be able to take 3 exercises from each section and then combine them into their own set. How would I take 3 random exercises? I have tried using random.sample with no luck

```
musclegroup_exercises = {
    'legs': {"squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"},
    'chest': {"barbell bench", "pushups", "cable fly", "dumbbell fly", "dumbbell incline bench press"},
    'arms': {"bicep curls", "kickbacks", "tricep pushdown", "reverse curls", "hammer curl"},
    'shoulders':{"shoulder press", "lateral raise", "barbell shrug", "bent over reverse flys", "push press"},
    'back':{"dumbbell rows", "back extension", "pull ups", "lat pull downs", "machine seated row"},
    'core':{"sit ups", "crunches", "russian twists", "bicycles", "planks"},
}

print('Here are the possible muscle groups you can target: Legs, Chest, Arms, Shoulders, Back, Core')
print('Here are the possible intensity levels: Easy, Medium, Hard')

num = int(input('Would you like to target one or two muscle groups? '))
if num == 1:
    musclegroup = input('What muscle group would you like to target?  ')
if num == 2: 
    musclegroup1 = input('What is the first musclegroup you would like to target? ')
    musclegroup2 = input('What is the second musclegroup you would like to target? ')    
intensity = input('What intensity level would you like? ')
if intensity == 'Easy':
    rate = '65%'
if intensity == 'Medium':
    rate = '80%'
if intensity == 'Hard':
    rate = '90%'
def createworkout1(y):
    for exercise in musclegroup_exercises[musclegroup.lower()]:
        print(exercise)    
def createworkout2(j,k):
    import random
    half1 = random.sample(musclegroup_exercises[musclegroup1.lower()].items(),3)
```

Comment: How does this account for the user input musclegroup1, which is the part of the dictionary I want to sample from

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shuffle`:

```
from itertools import chain
from random import shuffle

musclegroup_exercises = {
    'legs': {"squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"},
    'chest': {"barbell bench", "pushups", "cable fly", "dumbbell fly", "dumbbell incline bench press"},
    'arms': {"bicep curls", "kickbacks", "tricep pushdown", "reverse curls", "hammer curl"},
    'shoulders':{"shoulder press", "lateral raise", "barbell shrug", "bent over reverse flys", "push press"},
    'back':{"dumbbell rows", "back extension", "pull ups", "lat pull downs", "machine seated row"},
    'core':{"sit ups", "crunches", "russian twists", "bicycles", "planks"},
}

def shuffled_group(group):
    group = [i for i in group]
    shuffle(group)
    return group

selected_groups = ["back", "core"]  # This should come from your input, though, not be hardcoded.

targets = list(chain(*(shuffled_group(v)[:3] for k, v in musclegroup_exercises.items()) if k in selected_groups))
```

This could also work, though `sample` is being deprecated for sets so you have to do some more work:

```
list(chain(*(sample(list(v), 3) for k, v in musclegroup_exercises.items() if k in selected_groups)))
```

Comment: This works, now how do I get it to only shuffle a certain area which is specified by musclegroup1? For example if a user inputs 'legs'.

Comment: @FernandoToledo You want to update `selected_groups` to be a list containing the areas they want to focus on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample()`. Pass as parameters the list from which to get the elements and the length of the new list.

```
import random

musclegroup_exercises = {
    "legs":["squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"],
    "chest":["barbell bench", "pushups", "cable fly", "dumbbell fly", "dumbbell incline bench press"],
    "arms":["bicep curls", "kickbacks", "tricep pushdown", "reverse curls", "hammer curl"],
    "shoulders":["shoulder press", "lateral raise", "barbell shrug", "bent over reverse flys", "push press"],
    "back":["dumbbell rows", "back extension", "pull ups", "lat pull downs", "machine seated row"],
    "core":["sit ups", "crunches", "russian twists", "bicycles", "planks"],
}

random_exercises = {}
exercises_per_group = 3
for exercise_type in musclegroup_exercises:
    exercises = exercise = random.sample(musclegroup_exercises[exercise_type], exercises_per_group)
    random_exercises[exercise_type] = exercises
```

**NOTE:** *Always import the packages you need at the beginning of the program, do not import them in the meantime inside an if or functions.*

To take the exercises from only one area, you can simply change the key you use to access to `musclegroup_exercises`:

```
import random

musclegroup_exercises = {
    "legs":["squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"],
    "chest":["barbell bench", "pushups", "cable fly", "dumbbell fly", "dumbbell incline bench press"],
    "arms":["bicep curls", "kickbacks", "tricep pushdown", "reverse curls", "hammer curl"],
    "shoulders":["shoulder press", "lateral raise", "barbell shrug", "bent over reverse flys", "push press"],
    "back":["dumbbell rows", "back extension", "pull ups", "lat pull downs", "machine seated row"],
    "core":["sit ups", "crunches", "russian twists", "bicycles", "planks"],
}

exercises_per_group = 3
exercise_type = "legs"
exercises = random.sample(musclegroup_exercises[exercise_type], exercises_per_group)
```

Comment: A few notes to your notes - since you import `random` at the top you can just say `sample`. Secondly, braces around a list of objects (rather than a list of key-value tuples) will create a `set` and *not* a `dict`.  It's perfectly reasonable to use a set here if you want to ensure that you are not including duplicates.

Comment: This works, thank you!

Comment: @NathanielFord But to be able to write only `sample` I would have to write `from random import sample`. As for the sets, you're right, I totally forgot.

Comment: @FernandoToledo If the answer is right, please mark it as 'right answer'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `random.choices` since `sample` is deprecated:

```py
exercices = [j for z in [random.choices(tuple(musclegroup_exercises[i]),k=3) for i in (musclegroup1, musclegroup2)] for j in z]
```

Or in more understandable form:

```py
exercices = []
for i in (musclegroup1, musclegroup2):
    exercices.extend(random.choices(tuple(musclegroup_exercises[i]), k=3))
```